# Python parallel processing sudden shutdown

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, parallel-processing

While running some parallelized code in python, my dual boot (Windows 11 / Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) laptop suddenly shut down on multiple occasions. Afterwards, when running in Windows, my laptop has also randomly shut down and once booting Ubuntu, the screen started glitching a lot. I've been running the code on Ubuntu. My laptop has 12 cores.

The following set-up is how I run my parallel processing - as how I've learned it online:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = list(tqdm(executor.map(CONN.connection, input)))
```

where `CONN.connection` is a function in another file and `input` is a list of input arguments (a couple 1000 entries long).

I've tried breaking up the parallel processing to run only 1000 entries, then dump all the data using pickle and then running the next 1000 entries in my input list, but it still shut down after a couple 1000 function calls/processes.

**My question is:**
Seeing as my laptop has suddenly shut down on multiple occasions, is it safe for my system and hardware to run the program on all 12 cores, or should I cap it below that?

If you need any other info, I'd gladly supply them.

Comment: What is "CONN.connection" actually doing?

Comment: It is integrating two initial value problems and returning the value of the ends of those (in search of a connection). More specifically, spacecraft trajectories from Earth's L2 point (where the James Webb Space Telescope is headed currently) and an asteroid's L1 point. Takes about a second to do a single calculation with that function.

Comment: Does it use the GPU or CPU(s) only?  Does it use special libraries? Does it run external commands?

Comment: I was writing a response to your question and then my PC suddenly shut down again. This time I wasn't doing any computations - though I did open VSCode 5 minutes ago. So maybe it is not related to the parallel programming intensity?
To answer your questions: the function runs on CPU, (hadn't thought of doing it on GPU yet, I'm new to parallel processing). It only uses scipy to do the integration, astropy to convert times between JD, and json to read a json data file with asteroid data (the file is quite large) - though it doesn't store the entire file only a few entries corresponding.

Comment: The json file I'm reading is 17MB, fyi. I've read that multi-threading is better for i/o based operations, but since the majority of the functionality is number-crunching based, I though multi-processing would suit this problem best.

Comment: So there is nothing unusual in the code. Your way to run multiprocessing also looks ok. Together with the sudden unrelated shutdown I guess that the laptop itself has a problem, not the program.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, a bit late, but still thanks for thinking along. I managed to figure out what it was that caused the random shutdowns. On the Windows side of my dual-boot system, HP Sure Run was running (which, it says, is 'hardware enforced'). I think that means that when I'm running Ubuntu and doing something HP Sure Run doesn't like, it manages to interfere and shutdown the system. So I turned it off and now it hasn't happened since. Glad it wasn't due to processor overload or something (though I am running on 9 cores now instead of 12, just to be sure).

Comment: I'd like to close this question now. not sure how, though, without an answer to pick as 'chosen'.

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure out what it was that caused the random shutdowns. On the Windows side of my dual-boot system, HP Sure Run was running (which, it says, is 'hardware enforced'). I think that means that when I'm running Ubuntu and doing something HP Sure Run doesn't like, it manages to interfere and shutdown the system. So I turned it off and now it hasn't happened since. Glad it wasn't due to processor overload or something (though I am running on 9 cores now instead of 12, just to be sure).

Comment: Did this remain the case?